# Unity3d UnityWebRequest EscapeURL standard does not match Swift url encoding. How to decode it?

Tags: unity, networking, unityscript, unity-networking

How should I decode escaped URL by unity in Swift?

I am developing a game with Unity3d. Something MMORPG. With server implemented by me in `Swift` under `Kitura framework`
A framework doesn't matter that much. It is more about swift and Unity itself.

Let me describe the problem here.

Unity

```
UnityWebRequest.EscapeURL("First Last")
```

Escapes string with encoding used in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1
Which produce string `First+Last` where `+` maps to `" "` space.

Swift:

```
import Foundation


var str = "First+Last"
print(str)
print(str.removingPercentEncoding)
```

The character used on this string `+` isn't considered as a percentage encoding in the standard used by `swift`. It would be if the character escaped as this would be represented by `%20`.

So my server and client ended up with different string values. 
Later on returned from one to the other weren't equal. Which ended up considering them as two different clients.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason: Unity uses a different standard to escapes URLs then swift one.

Escapes string with encoding used in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1 Which produce string First+Last where + maps to " " space.

Possible solution: Is to replace `"+"` by yourself with `" "` before attempting to encode URL in swift.

```
"Encoded+String%2B".replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: " ").removingPercentEncoding
```